# Refer to Excel Undolist language independent

Tags: excel, vba

I have used an Excel macro that automatically pastes all data as values, by undoing the pasting and pasting it as value.

This is the code:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
Dim UndoList As String

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False

On Error GoTo Whoa

'~~> Get the undo List to capture the last action performed by user
UndoList = Application.CommandBars("Standard").Controls("&Undo").List(1)

'~~> Check if the last action was not a paste nor an autofill
If Left(UndoList, 5) <> "Paste" And UndoList <> "Auto Fill" _
Then GoTo LetsContinue

'~~> Undo the paste that the user did but we are not clearing
'~~> the clipboard so the copied data is still in memory
Application.Undo

If UndoList = "Auto Fill" Then Selection.Copy

'~~> Do a pastespecial to preserve formats
On Error Resume Next
'~~> Handle text data copied from a website
Target.Select
ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial Format:="Text", _
Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False

Target.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, _
SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
On Error GoTo 0

'~~> Retain selection of the pasted data
Union(Target, Selection).Select

LetsContinue:
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
Exit Sub
Whoa:
MsgBox Err.Description
Resume LetsContinue
End Sub
```

I am using the English Excel version where it works fine, however when other users, who e.g. have a German Excel version paste something, they get a procedure error in this line:

```
UndoList = Application.CommandBars("Standard").Controls("&Undo").List(1)
```

I guess the Undo command is named differently in German.

Is there a way to define the Undo list independent of the language the user is using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the Control's Id number instead.

```
debug.Print Application.CommandBars("Standard").Controls("&Undo").Id
=> 128 

debug.Print Application.CommandBars("Standard").FindControl(Id:=128).caption
=> &Undo
```

Comment: Thanks, for your reply. I am not sure how to use that id to replace the line. I tried `UndoList = Application.CommandBars("Standard").Controls(128).List(1)` and `UndoList = Application.CommandBars("Standard").Controls(ID:=128).List(1)` but had no success. Also defining a string with `undoname = Application.CommandBars("Standard").FindControl(Id:=128).caption` and then using `UndoList = Application.CommandBars("Standard").Controls(undoname).List(1)` did not work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Mustika `Application.CommandBars("Standard").FindControl(ID:=128).List(1)`

Comment: @Mustika Note that if the undo list is empty, this will throw an error. Check `Application.CommandBars("Standard").FindControl(ID:=128).ListCount > 0` first.

Comment: Weird: in my install of Excel365 `Application.CommandBars(14).FindControl(ID:=128).List(1)` no longer works.

Answer (score 1):

You should also substitute in the code the words "Paste", "Auto fill" and "Text" for your local language words.

Answer (score 0):

Use the index as name:

```
undoname = Application.CommandBars("Standard").FindControl(ID:=128).Index
UndoList = Application.CommandBars("Standard").Controls(undoname).List(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

Very useful code. Thank you.
Can do this also:

```
UndoList = Application.CommandBars("Standard").FindControl(ID:=128).List(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

The "List(1)" is a name too in a concrete language. Has the List(1) values ("Paste", "Autofill") any unique ID's?

```
Application.CommandBars("Standard").FindControl(ID:=128).List(1).Id
or
Application.CommandBars("Standard").FindControl(ID:=128).List(1).Index
don't work.
```