# Get last user action (change) independent of language

Tags: vba, xls

I'm currently checking the undo control list to get the last action/change done by the user (as in [Refer to Excel Undo List language independent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24391518/vba-refer-to-excel-undolist-language-independent)) - which works (almost) perfectly.

However this list contains language dependent text, which is quite inconvenient if you need language independent code. Its not even guaranteed that the last action (e.g. `Paste`) can always be identified by the first word of the text entry.

So my question is, if anybody is aware of a better, language independent, more programmatic way to detect the last command/action of the user.

Any help is highly welcome.